# how to add the existing row from a datagridview to another one by clicking button "enter" at the row?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, enter

i have two datagridviews,one for previewing some items and another one to store data

i just want to accept the Enter button as the double click on a row 
note that when i use the DoubleClick event it gives me back the row's data which is the right.
but when i use the KeyDown event and use enter button 
it gives the info of the next row ! which is not right.
here what i tried by

```
  private void datagridlistcust_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                Close();
            }
        }
```

and this is how i fill the text

```
    TXTIDPROD.Text = FRM.DGVPRODUCTS.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    TXTNAMEPROD.Text = FRM.DGVPRODUCTS.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    TXTPRICE.Text = FRM.DGVPRODUCTS.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
```

then finally this how i fill the second datagridview

```
private void TXTDISCOUNT_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                DataRow r = dt.NewRow();
               r[0] = TXTIDPROD.Text;
            r[1] = TXTNAMEPROD.Text;
            r[2] = TXTPRICE.Text;
            r[3] = TXTAMOUNT.Text;
            r[4] = TXTTOTAL.Text;
            r[5] = TXTDISCOUNT.Text;
            r[6] = TXTAFTERDIS.Text;
            dt.Rows.Add(r);
            datagridview1.DataSource = dt;

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple way to do this:

```
public Form()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // subscribe double click event handler
    dataGrid.DoubleClick += txtHost_DoubleClick;

    // subscribe keypress event handler
    dataGrid.KeyPress += txtHost_KeyPress;
}

void dataGrid_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // check for Enter Key Press
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    { 
        // Call the double click event handler
        dataGrid_DoubleClick(sender, e);
    }
}
void dataGrid_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Your Code here to handle double click event
}
```

Comment: it still getting the data of the next row to be selected :

Comment: You just have to handle the double click event and when enter is press double click event handler will be executed.